# Discord - Send message only from python app to discord channel (one way communication)

Tags: python, bots, discord, python-asyncio, discord.py

I am designing an app where I can send notification to my discord channel when something happen with my python code (e.g new user signup on my website). It will be a one way communication as only python app will send message to discord channel.

Here is what I have tried.

```
import os
import discord
import asyncio


TOKEN = ""
GUILD = ""

def sendMessage(message):
    client = discord.Client()

    @client.event
    async def on_ready():


        channel = client.get_channel(706554288985473048)
        await channel.send(message)
        print("done")

        return ""


    client.run(TOKEN)
    print("can you see me?")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    sendMessage("abc")
    sendMessage("def")
```

The issue is only first message is being sent (i-e abc) and then aysn function is blocking the second call (def).

I don't need to listen to discord events and I don't need to keep the network communication open. Is there any way where I can just post the text (post method of api like we use normally) to discord server without listening to events?

Thanks.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can send the message to a Discord webhook.

First, [make a webhook](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks) in the Discord channel you'd like to send messages to.

Then, use the [`discord.Webhook.from_url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook.from_url) method to fetch a [`Webhook`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook) object from the URL Discord gave you.

Finally, use the [`discord.Webhook.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Webhook.send) method to send a message using the webhook.

If you're using version 2 of discord.py, you can use this snippet:

```
from discord import SyncWebhook

webhook = SyncWebhook.from_url("url-here")
webhook.send("Hello World")
```

Otherwise, you can make use of the [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) module:

```
import requests
from discord import Webhook, RequestsWebhookAdapter

webhook = Webhook.from_url("url-here", adapter=RequestsWebhookAdapter())
webhook.send("Hello World")
```

Comment: This is awesome and is a prefect answer to the question, just bare in mind that webhooks can only post to CHANNELS, not direct messages to users or so on.

Comment: how would I do it for Direct messages?

Comment: @TendekaiMuchenje Webhooks won't work in direct messages. You'd need to make a bot and send the messages programmatically via the bot.

Answer (score 25):

I have found it. "Webhook" is the answer. Instead of using discord.py, just create a webhook for your channle and then just post the data to that endpoint.

```
import requests

#Webhook of my channel. Click on edit channel --> Webhooks --> Creates webhook
mUrl = "https://discord.com/api/webhooks/729017161942******/-CC0BNUXXyrSLF1UxjHMwuHA141wG-FjyOSDq2Lgt*******************"

data = {"content": 'abc'}
response = requests.post(mUrl, json=data)

print(response.status_code)

print(response.content)
```

Answer (score 3):

This might be one of the best approaches as it saves the addition of more python packages(one mentioned by @john), but I believe there is a more robust and easy solution for this scenario, as you can add images, make tables and make those notifications look more expressive.

A [python library](https://pypi.org/project/discord-webhook/) designed for the explicit purpose of sending a message to the discord server. A simple example from the PyPI page would be:

```
from discord_webhook import DiscordWebhook

webhook = DiscordWebhook(url='your webhook url', content='Webhook Message')
response = webhook.execute()
```

more examples follow on the page.

[This is how the sent notification/message would look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdnMu.png)

[Discord notification with table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw0JI.png)