# How to make my custom discord bot sends message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Im trying to make my custom bot sends a custom message using python

Me: ~repeat Hi

My Message deleted

custom-Bot: Hi

whenever I try using this I get error problems with this code specifically "client"

await **client**.delete_message(ctx.message)

return await **client**.say(mesg)

```
from discord.ext import commands 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '~') #sets prefix 

@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def repeat(ctx, *args):
    mesg = ' '.join(args)
    await client.delete_message(ctx.message)
    return await client.say(mesg)

client.run('Token')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord - Send message only from python app to discord channel (one way communication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62731561/discord-send-message-only-from-python-app-to-discord-channel-one-way-communic)

Answer (score 1):

`client` does not have an attribute called `delete_message`, to delete the author's message use [`ctx.message.delete`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.delete). To send a message in the rewrite branch of discord.py, you use [`await ctx.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send)

```
@client.command()
async def repeat(ctx, *args):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    await ctx.send(' '.join(args))
```