# How to quit a discord bot without using 'except' python

Tags: python, discord.py

need quick help this is the code that simply posts to a discord channel I am using it as a subpart of my project all I want from this to post and shuts (without killing the program) so I can't use 'exit', I have used while loops and all that but nothing is working.

```
def post_discord():
    print('POSTING NEW OFFER TO DISCORD')
    token = 'token here'
    while True:
        bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
        @bot.command()
        async def on_ready():

            await bot.wait_until_ready()
            channel = bot.get_channel(12345678) # replace with channel ID that you want to send to
                # await channel.send()
            await channel.send(text,file =discord.File('promo.png'))

            await asyncio.sleep(2)

            # exit()
            # await bot.close()





        bot.loop.create_task(on_ready())

        bot.run(token)
        time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: I'd suggest using a Discord webhook instead.
See detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731999/6169862)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* want to just stop the bot from running after it finishes doing whatever you want it to do, what you're looking for is `discord.Client.logout()`. In your scenario, the usage would be `bot.logout()`

Although, as someone who replied to your post said, a webhook *may* be more suitable for your use case. A simple webhook for sending a message using `requests` would look something like this:

```
import requests


data = {"content": "Message Content"}
requests.post("Webhook URL", data=data)
```

Discord's documentation for this can be found [here](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook), notable limitations for this route are that you're unable to attach files, but if you're just needing to send an image along with some text, a .png link may suffice as Discord will hide the link in the message.