# Discord.py send messages outside of events

Tags: python, discord

Discord.py seems to be designed around a bot listening for events like `on_ready` or `on_message` etc. But I would like to know if there us any way I can create my connection, and then send messages outside of the connection.

This question and answer is PERFECT for my need except that webhooks don't allow messages to people directly: [Discord - Send message only from python app to discord channel (one way communication)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62731561/discord-send-message-only-from-python-app-to-discord-channel-one-way-communic)

Here is code that works totally fine (it can send messages to users directly)

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    the_user = await client.fetch_user(PERSON_ID)
    await the_user.send('Hi')
client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

But my problem is I need more of a webhook design where I can do something like this (pseudo code):

```
import my_discord_class
client = my_discord_class.connect(TOKEN)
client.send(PERSON_ID, 'Hi')
```

Any suggestions how I can get around this? Essentially I need to send stuff outside of these "events".

Comment: You can send messages anywhere (including outside events, eg in tasks) where you have the client like in cogs.
What you want to do can't be done in a sync environment and also code after connect doesn't get run until the bot's event loop stops running.
If you want to go outside events either use tasks, the HTTP routes directly or `client.loop.run_until_complete(your_function())`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ali but would you mind posting a simple example please?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need anything else and just wanna send a dm then you may use the discord raw API without using discord.py

```py
import requests

TOKEN = "Your Bot's Token"
USER_ID = Some User ID

BASE_URL = f"https://discord.com/api/v9"
SEND_URL = BASE_URL + "/channels/{id}/messages"
DM_URL = BASE_URL + f"/users/@me/channels"

headers = {
    "Authorization": f"Bot {TOKEN}",
    "User-Agent": f"DiscordBot"
}

dm_channel = requests.post(DM_URL, headers=headers, json={"recipient_id": USER_ID})
dm_channel_id = dm_channel.json()["id"]
r = requests.post(SEND_URL.format(id=dm_channel_id), headers=headers, json={"content": "Text Here"})
```

Here we are using the [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) module to make an HTTP POST request to the [discord API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro). first, we are [creating a dm channel](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#create-dm). and getting its id, this only needs to be done once and after that, the id would stay the same for that specific user so if you want to dm the same person multiple times, just print dm_channel_id and store it and use it the next time I guess. Then we are [sending a message to the dm channel](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message) using its ID. here in the example I only showed content, but you can add more stuff like embeds and such. [see the documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#create-message-jsonform-params) for more info

Comment: So this creates a channel (group) between the bot and the user right? If that is the case, then this isn't a perfect solution. Would be better if I could just message the user (like another user would)...but regardless this is an awesome idea and it does indirectly solve my problem :)

Comment: @Frank the dm channel creation only needs to be done once so if you have some way of saving the dm_channel id then the dm channel creation is unnecessary. also if you look at the [dpy source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/user.py#L455) you'll see that it too creates a dm channel when you try to dm a user. the discord API does not allow you to directly send a dm and that's a *discord limitation* and there's nothing you can do about it. and even the discord PC client creates a dm channel when you 1. send a friend req 2. message someone 3. ctrl+k into someone etc.

Comment: if you look at the [request logs of the discord client](https://imgur.com/a/BHSEVws) you'll see that it too creates a dm when you try to send a message to a user