# How can I send the result of this little python script to a Discord Webhook?

Tags: discord, discord.py, webhooks

How can I send a message to discord with the result of status and status?

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from itertools import count
from tkinter import W
from typing import List
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd



url = 'https://contabo-status.com'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

#ESTATUS

st = soup.find_all ('span', class_='tab_headline')

status = list()

count = 0
for i in st:
    if count < 1:
        status.append(i.text)
    else:
        break
    count +=1
#ESTATUS2

st2 = soup.find_all ('div', class_='content_inner_body')

status2 = list()

for i in st2:
    status2.append(i.text)

print (status)
print('')
print(status2)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731999/11420970) answer your question?