# How can I set my bot to clean status in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

How can I set my bot to clean status in discord.py?
For example:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUAy8.png)

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = discord.AutoShardedBot(shards=2, intents = intents)
intents.members=True
token = "TOKEN"


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.invisible)

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: What happened when you ran your code?

Comment: It's an HTTP bot, that's why it is not showing the status.

Comment: What is the difference between an HTTP bot and mine?

Answer (score 0):

As @Dominik mentioned in the comments, the bot in the example is not the type of bot that connects through the Discord gateway. Instead, they run through the application webhook. For more information check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62731999/8658598) answer.

Comment: OK, but what does it have to do with the fact that I can't make a simple status like in this picture: [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUAy8.png)

Comment: You can't achieve that with `discord.Bot` or `discord.AutoShardedBot` ...

Comment: But then how can I do it?