Error 401 while sending message via requests in discord
Here's my code to begin:
import requests

header = {"authorization": '[Redacted]'
         }
payload = {'content': "Test"}

r = requests.post(
  'https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/[Redacted]/messages',
                data=payload,
                headers=header
            )
print(r.status_code)

I want to send a message to a specific channel via my account (not through a bot). The code provided above used to work just fine for me a while back, but now it returns error code 401 [Unauthorized request]

This topic has a few good answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62731561/discord-send-message-only-from-python-app-to-discord-channel-one-way-communic

Verify whether the authorization token or channel ID is correct.
Your code is correct:
header = {"authorization": token}
payload = {"content": "Test"}

r = requests.post(
    f"https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/{channel_id}/messages",
    data=payload,
    headers=header,
)
print(r.status_code)

Output: 200

Oh...my auth key had changed....i had the token saved in a txt file locally and thats what i'd been referring to to copy it, just went to networks and copied it from there, and turns out its different from the one i had written down for the same account...
didnt know it changed...haha, it really was a stupid question, Tysm tho <3
